# Creating new users in SQL Azure

Tags: sql, database, security, azure, roles

I have been assigned the task of converting an SQL Server Database to an SQL Azure Database. During the process I encountered these problems:

1. **Cannot use the Object Browser in Management Studio 2008** v10. Is there a fix to this?
2. I **cannot create new Users under the Security Section** since I cant use the Object   Browser.
   Basically I want to create an **Admin** user and **NonAdmin** user each with their own privileges to UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT commands on different tables in the database.
3. Basically my web application has a sign up form how can I **associate new registered user to the SQL Azure Roles** during the sign up process to limit them from perfroming ertain commands on the database tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the official page on how to move data etc..'Migrating Databases to SQL Azure'

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee730904.aspx

Also check out the 'SQL Azure Migration Wizard v3.8.3'
http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/

Migrating Databases to SQL Azure by Using Data-tier Application Export and Import is probably your best option, the migration wizard is a great tool, I have used both.

re: 1 you need service packs, I'm not sure 2008 V10 is supported, get the latest version or upgrade to 2008R2 Mgmt Studio (latest)
2: use the tools above
3: not sure here what you are trying to do to correctly answer.

hope that helps...

Answer (score 1):

Just answer your questions.

1, No SSMS 2008 doesn't support Azure. You MUST use SSMS 08 R2.

2, If you are using SSMS 08 R2 the object explorer will be appeared. But the features when connecting to SQL Azure will be very limited. The designer and dialog are disabled which means all tasks should be done by using the SQL script.

3, Not pretty sure what you mean, but you can try what you are doing on SQL Server since SQL Azure is very very similar with SQL Server.

Data-tier Application and SQL Azure MW are good tool for migrating your existing database to SQL Azure. But you can still use the build-in feature in SSMS 08 R2 to migrate the database schema as well. Just use the Generate Script menu item from your local database, and make sure you selected SQL Azure in the "Script for the database engine type".